# Parse filtered data with D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm loading data and then I allow it to be filtered using a checkbox. I have to parse the date field in the data every time the data is updated by the checkbox.  Below is my script.  This works for the very first click on the checkbox but fails for subsequent clicks...  And produces this error: Any ideas why this is happening?

> Uncaught TypeError: t.slice is not a function

```
var apiData = [ {resource_type: "Books", date_posted: "3/8/2007",total_donations:43},
                     {resource_type: "Supplies", date_posted: "11/11/2002",total_donations:65}];

$(":checkbox").change(function() {
  var dataSet = apiData.filter(function(el) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('result');
    var index = 0;
    var found = false;
    while (index < checkboxes.length) {
      if (checkboxes[index].checked && el.resource_type == checkboxes[index].value) found = true;
      ++index;
    }
    return found;
  });
  ///Need to figure out how to evaluate this!!!***********************************************************************************    
  var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y");
  dataSet.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date_posted = dateFormat.parse(d.date_posted);
    d.date_posted.setDate(1);
    d.total_donations = +d.total_donations;
  });
});
```

Comment: any chance we can see the values of `apiData`?

Comment: I think that's how the data comes through.  I might have found a clue...  It looks like on the first click of the checkbox it parses the data.  Then on the second click it tries to parse the already parsed data again...  Could that be a problem?  Maybe if I load the apiData and parse it and then apply the filtering it would work...  will try and update.

Comment: Update!  That was the problem.  Once the data is parsed it can't be parsed again.  So on checkbox change after the first change it erred.  I took the parse function outside of the checkbox change function. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

The date_posted field needed to be parsed just once outside of the .change() function.  A parsed field can't be parsed again.

```
var apiData = [ {resource_type: "Books", date_posted: "3/8/2007",total_donations:43},
                         {resource_type: "Supplies", date_posted: "11/11/2002",total_donations:65}];

  var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y");
  apiData.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date_posted = dateFormat.parse(d.date_posted);
    d.date_posted.setDate(1);
    d.total_donations = +d.total_donations;
  });

$(":checkbox").change(function() {
  var dataSet = apiData.filter(function(el) {
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('result');
    var index = 0;
    var found = false;
    while (index < checkboxes.length) {
      if (checkboxes[index].checked && el.resource_type == checkboxes[index].value) found = true;
      ++index;
    }
    return found;
  });
});
```